Problems with urls at Laravel 11
I have been having problems for a few days regarding access to routes defined for my middlewares. The specific problem with all this is that when, for example, I want to enter a URL of my entity other than Users, it always returns me to the home page, regardless of the user role that the logged-in user has. I leave important parts of the code here in case someone knows why it could be:
Model of Users:
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'rol_usuario',
        'fecha_nacimiento',
        'sexo',
        'tarjeta_credito',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}

Login function in UsuariosController:
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            Log::info('Inicio de sesión exitoso para el email: ' . $request->input('email'));
            return redirect()->route('home');
        }

        return back()->withErrors([
            'email' => 'Las credenciales son incorrectas.',
        ])->onlyInput('email');
    }

Middleware for administrators:
public function handle($request, Closure $next) : Response
    {
        if (!Auth::check()) {
            return redirect()->route('login.form')->withErrors('Debes iniciar sesión para acceder a esta página.');
        }
    
        if (Auth::user()->rol_usuario !== 'administrador') {
            return redirect()->route('home')->withErrors('No tienes permiso para acceder a esta página.');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

web.php:
// Rutas de autenticación de usuarios
Route::get('login', [UsuariosController ::class, 'create'])->name('login');
Route::post('login', [UsuariosController::class, 'store']);
Route::post('logout', [UsuariosController::class, 'destroy'])->name('logout');
// Rutas para la gestión de carteras
Route::middleware(['auth', 'administrador'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('carteras', [CarteraController::class, 'index'])->name('carteras.index');
    Route::get('carteras/create', [CarteraController::class, 'create'])->name('carteras.create');
    Route::post('carteras/create', [CarteraController::class, 'store'])->name('carteras.store');
});

I have tried to introduce the user_role attribute to the $credentials variable but it does not take it in any way, for the urls of the Users entity I have no problem accessing it, but for Portfolio only the index of the methods created in its controller is accessible.

First of all you cannot add anything to credentials variable. Because you use this variable to check user can log in to your system or not.
I mean attempt function has specific inputs so if you want to add other values to your credentials, you should customize attempt function and write custom algorithm.
If you want to handle role-permissions in your application you can use laravel spattie package.
Otherwise you can debug your application if you don't like spatie package complexity. So add dd(Auth::user()->rol_usuario) inside middleware to find out what your user role is. Make sure your user has the required role.

Thanks mate! I'll try to learn more about Spattie.

you're welcome. If there are any other questions or problems, feel free to ask me.
